# Why isn't react native displaying my background image?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, compiler-errors, cross-platform

The following code below compiles into react native just fine and the I don't recieve any errors in any of the compilers but my android emulator remains blank instead of displaying a background image like it's suppose to. Does anyone know why?

**Code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';

import bgImage from './Images/background.jpg' 

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <ImageBackground source={bgImage} style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
      </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroundContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width:null, 
    height:null, 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: try `<ImageBackground soure={require('./Images/background.jpg' )} style={styles.backgroundContainer}>`

Comment: Accept his answer man... don't just leave the question unanswer even it already have the answer...

Comment: Very late here but noticed there's a typo on the code. It should be `source={bgImage}` instead of soure={bgImage}

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <ImageBackground source={require(./Images/background.jpg)} style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
          <Text> Here Background Image </Text>
      </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroundContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width:'100%', 
    height:'100%',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use require

```
 <ImageBackground soure={require(bgImage)} style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
      </ImageBackground>
```

Comment: I tried this actually and it didn't work. I got an error saying:"  bundling failed: Error: App.js:Invalid call at line 19: require(_background.default)".

Comment: what is _background.default ? you should use require(bgImage)

Answer (score 0):

`source={require(BgIMage)}`  You missed the `require`